# Methods for figuring out the best schools for a particular field of study

Tags: research-process, graduate-school, research-group

I am about to graduate in Electrical Engineering and I wanted to pursue graduate studies in a field such as coding theory or software defined and cognitive radio.

But I'm not sure where to find the information needed to decide which school to choose. University rankings won't be specific enough to point out the quality of the research groups of my interest. I was looking for something that would point out volume and relevance of papers and articles published by the Universities' research groups.

I don't need answers on which school is best, but tools to figure this out by myself.

Answer (score 5):

Research groups that are active in a particular field will publish often in those fields.

So, identify conferences* in your field of interest. Look at the technical programs for the last couple of years, and check out the groups that seem to be contributing a lot.

Also, ask professors at your undergrad university who work in related fields.

* Also workshops, large conferences with a few on-topic sessions, journals, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question.

But if you are targeting a specific field of research, it might be better if you go with a well-known supervisor than a high-ranked school. I know that the name of the school and hence its ranking is important when you graduate from there, but the importance of the supervisor is something you should not overlook at all.

Just my two cents.

Comment: Would you say a good "measurement" would be number of citations a certain researcher received, as shown in Google Scholar?

Comment: Yes of course. But you should always check whether they are STILL active in a specific field of research. For that purpose, you can check their recent published papers. The better conferences/journals that they publish, the better the quality of their research!